# Windows on Mac, unable to access OSX

Tags: macos, windows-8, boot-camp

I had windows 7 on my mac via bootcamp and now i removed windows 7 via bootcamp and then partitioned again via bootcamp to install windows 8. Bootcamp did nothing after the partition so I restarted my mac with the win8 disk inside the tray and windows 8 installed! I lost my windows utilities disk and unable to access my mac, so no drivers absolutely and wifi is not working because of the same. Any help on rescuing my osx ?

Comment: I faced a similar situation. But i was able to access OS X. Are you sure you lost access to Mac? Did you try booting with the Option Key pressed? It must list all the bootable partitions

Comment: yes i am positive i lost access! I tried command + r, command + l .. it just boots into windows !

Comment: command doesn't work.. the option key must be pressed. I personally feel your OS X is intact..

Comment: Try holding down `Option` *during the boot*..

Comment: tried with option, not happening, still booting into windows!

Comment: Well the only way I could fix this was by searching for my bootcamp disc and install it from windows. Is there no other way to fix this? I am sure I will lose the disc someday and be stuck on windows!